# I need an anchor in one for loop to scroll to paragraph in another for loop. (Angular io)

Tags: angular

In my example, I would like the move the #content template reference variable into the paragraph element, so that my link will scroll to the corresponding paragraph. Would interpolation work to make the reference unique?

Something like this:

```
<nav>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" *ngFor="let item of data; let i = index"  (click)="scroll(content)">Go To {{item.section}}</a>
</nav>

<div>
<p #content *ngFor="let item of data; let i = index" #content{{i}}>
  {{item.content}}  
<p>
</div>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gipbfk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [ViewChildren](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren) decorator for get paragraphs from template and get needed paragraph by index:

```
 @ViewChildren('paragrapth') paragraghs: QueryList<ElementRef<HTMLElement>>;

  data = [
    { section: 'Section One',
      content: 'Section One: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.'
    },
    { section: 'Section Two',
      content: 'Section Two: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.'
    },
    { section: 'Section Three',
      content: 'Section Three: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.'
    }
  ];
  
  scroll(index: number) {
    const nodes = this.paragraghs.toArray();
    nodes[index].nativeElement.scrollIntoView();
  }
```

Template:

```
<nav>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" *ngFor="let item of data; let i = index"  (click)="scroll(i)">Go To {{item.section}}</a>
</nav>

<div>
  <p #paragrapth *ngFor="let item of data; let i = index" >
    {{item.content}}  
  <p>
</div>
```

But if you don't need to use `{ behavior: smooth }` for scroll, you can add unig Id to every item and just use `id` attribute and [anchor links](https://www.rapidtables.com/web/html/link/html-anchor-link.html)

Comment: you can use directly find with the index to get the element in the QueryList at one index: `this.contentSections.find((x,i)=>i==index).nativeElement.scrollIntoView();`